# ImportError: cannot import name '_astype_copy_false' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Similar Question here, but unanswered
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56936651/python-package-shap-import)  [Python package SHAP import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56936651/python-package-shap-import)
I was having issues with KMeans in Python's SKlearn, so I reinstalled (not updated)
I went from version 0.19.2 to 0.22.1

Now, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-69ff3c3126ec> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from ._spectral import spectral_clustering, SpectralClustering
      7 from ._mean_shift import (mean_shift, MeanShift,
      8                           estimate_bandwidth, get_bin_seeds)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_spectral.py in <module>()
     13 from ..utils import check_random_state, as_float_array
     14 from ..utils.validation import check_array
---> 15 from ..metrics.pairwise import pairwise_kernels
     16 from ..neighbors import kneighbors_graph, NearestNeighbors
     17 from ..manifold import spectral_embedding

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py in <module>()
     36 from ._classification import multilabel_confusion_matrix
     37 
---> 38 from . import cluster
     39 from .cluster import adjusted_mutual_info_score
     40 from .cluster import adjusted_rand_score

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 - unsupervised, which does not and measures the 'quality' of the model itself.
      7 """
----> 8 from ._supervised import adjusted_mutual_info_score
      9 from ._supervised import normalized_mutual_info_score
     10 from ._supervised import adjusted_rand_score

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/_supervised.py in <module>()
     23 from ._expected_mutual_info_fast import expected_mutual_information
     24 from ...utils.validation import check_array, check_consistent_length
---> 25 from ...utils.fixes import comb, _astype_copy_false
     26 
     27 

ImportError: cannot import name '_astype_copy_false' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes' (/Users/shane/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py)
```

Answer (score 9):

Restart your kernel. It worked in my case.

Comment: I restarted my python IDE and it works too.

Comment: Same here, in VSCode